# Is it possible to generate a single Word document with content from multiple list items via a workflow? Or some other means?

Tags: workflow, document, word, document-template

I have a scenario where users will be adding list items to a custom list.  Once a week, a single word document needs to be generated that includes content from all of the list items added that week.

I have seen how, using a workflow, you can insert column data from a list item into a document template, but it seems as though this will generate one word document per list item, and I need to combine data from multiple list items into the same doc, formatted roughly as follows:

> **Column 1 value (from list item 1)**
>
> 1. Column 2 value (from list item 1)
> 2. Column 3 value (from list item 1)
>
> **Column 1 value (from list item 2)**
>
> 1. Column 2 value (from list item 2)
> 2. Column 3 value (from list item 2)
>
> etc...

Is there a way to set up a repeating templated section in a Word doc and have a workflow generate a new section per list item?  This could be a 2010 workflow or a 2013 workflow.

Or is this something I'm going to have to accomplish with C#?

Comment: Hi, where you able to get this working? I'm interested in doing something similar for monthly reports, taking office A and office B update for the month from a list and generating a word document with that.

Comment: @Yugo I was able to get it working, but not as a workflow.  I had to write some pretty extensive C# in a custom webpart and used the [OpenXML library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to interact with the Word document.  I did not use a timer job as suggested in the answer because I wanted the users to have the option of creating the document at whatever time they needed to, so, I made a webpart with a button that kicked off all the server-side processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible also workflow is not a best solution for this scenario. You need to create a custom SharePoint timer job and have it run on a weekly basis.

In the timer job solution, You can use C# and Open XML or office dll's to generate the custom word document based on the list fields.

you can refer the below links for better understanding:

[**Open XML**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440953(v=office.12).aspx)

[**Custom SP timer job creation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686(v=office.12).aspx)

Also, [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532473.aspx)

Apart from this, if you want to have an on-demand feature then you can even create a custom feature action based on list scope in which you can invoke an layouts page for generating the word documents.

[**Refer this**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768562(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: It does need to be on-demand and not a timer job.  I am going down the route of a custom ribbon action opening an application page which has the code to generate the document.  I'd just like to point out though that since we have to go to C# / code behind, it would also be possible to create a custom workflow activity that contains all the necessary code, and then use that custom activity in a workflow to generate the document.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to go beyond the microsoft eco-system, I have created a python script that translates a CSV into a PDF specification with an open source license if it helps you or the people stumbling upon your thread: https://github.com/JLoDoesIt/specification-latex
(knowing that CSV creation from Sharepoint list is beyond simplicity)

Comment: While I appreciate the contribution and don't mean to diminish your achievement with your script, CSV format (i.e. Excel-sheet-like table columns and rows) does not really meet the formatting goals of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since there has been some new activity on this question, I thought I'd take a moment to provide an updated answer for 2020/2021.

While the accepted answer stands, since C# code-behind and the OpenXML SDK was how I solved my problem back in 2015, I have recently done similar solutions entirely client-side in Javascript, by retrieving data from SharePoint lists through the REST API, assembling a Word doc completely in the browser using the [docx.js library](https://docx.js.org/) ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx)), and then saving the resulting `.docx` file back to SharePoint again using the REST API.

So this is now all possible in Javascript, without needing any C# server-side code.